# getInfoContents() is not called

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow

I'm trying to display two types info window on Google Map. when I clicked a marker, custom info window is called, but when I clicked Map, another custom info window isn't displayed. moreover I got log, I found that getInfoContents is not called within setOnMapClickListener. but getInfoContents within setOnMarkerListener is called.
...why?

```
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                        Log.v("a", "getInfoWindow");
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                        Log.v("a", "getInfoContents");
                        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker_default, null);
                        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.default_infowindow);
                        title.setText(mCompany);
                        return view;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker_window, null);
                        ImageView badge = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge);
                        badge.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                        TextView snippet = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
                        title.setText(mCompany);
                        snippet.setText(mAddress);
                        return view;
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Google Maps reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter.html), only one info window can show at a time. Also, the getInfoConents() method is called when a marker is tapped.

If you want to show an info window programmatically, you should call the [showInfoWindow()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows#showhide_an_info_window) method.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I forgot to make the activity aware of the callback.
Try adding this:

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(this);
```